# MonoTouch Memory Consumption Overhead for UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, mono

I have a very simple test application written out in `Objective-C` and in MonoTouch. The application adds `n` `UIWebView`'s to a blank `UIView` (each `UIWebView` is initialized, loads Google, and added as a subview using the code below). The memory consumption using `MonoTouch` vs. `Objective-C` is as follows:

#### Memory Consumption (Objective-C/MonoTouch):

- 0 UIWebView(s) Added: `1.29 MB` / `2.01 MB`
- 1 UIWebView(s) Added: `3.61 MB` / `11.53 MB`
- 10 UIWebView(s) Added: `4.00 MB` / `37.19 MB`

My question is, how come the MonoTouch equivalent code has such a large memory consumption overhead when compared to the equivalent `Objective-C` version and is there anything I can do about it? I'm particularly interested in the case where there are multiple `UIWebView`s (i.e. 10+).

### Relevant Code

#### C#/MonoTouch Version

```cs
WebView = new UIWebView(new RectangleF(0, 100, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 100)); 
WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(@"http://www.google.ca"))); 
View.AddSubview(WebView);
```

#### Objective-C/XCode Version

```c
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 100.0f)];
[webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.ca"]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: How did you measure the memory consumption? What numbers from Instruments did you use?

Comment: Also how did you build both ? for simulator or device ? and using which options (e.g. debug, LLVM) ? That can make a huge difference for Xamarin.iOS since the simulator uses the JIT and (by default) does not link your application. Device builds are AOT'ed and (by default) link all SDK assemblies.

Comment: When you remove the UIWebView: have you tried to `Dispose()`it actively? And then you'll need to wait for the garbage collector. Still, it would not explain why 10x the memory of the native version is used.

Comment: @Krumelur measured memory consumption using Instruments "Live Bytes" column. I did try to `Dispose()` actively right after removing the UIWebView from its superview and watched the memory consumption for a long period of time afterwards to no avail.

Comment: @poupou both were built for hardware devices. The MonoTouch version has LLVM enabled, debug disabled and I even tried the SGen GC option but it did not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code for both projects somewhere (e.g. github) ? I doubt you can have 10 live `UIWebView` with only 4MB (or my OSX Safari needs a serious diet from Apple).